# Too many things on one breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

So recently, my mother purchased a new house. Upon inspection, it was deemed that some electrical work needed to be done. The work happened and everything is all hunky dory till the other day when a breaker was tripped. That breaker controls half of the entire house. This includes the upstairs living room and bedrooms (2x) and then the downstairs living area and two more bedrooms. They are all on the same breaker. Is this up to code? It seems completely ridiculous to me and the electrical worker said everything was all good. Thoughts?

Comment: In order to say if it's "up to code", we probably need to know where you live.

Comment: I think a picture of the breaker will be helpful.

Comment: Modern code typically says 12 devices (lights or duplex outlets).  How many devices are we talking about?  You could have all the lighting on one breaker if there are only 6 room with 6 lights and each room only has one outlet and meet code.  Modern led lights have very little draw what did you plug in that tripped the breaker (a/c, dehumidifier, computer, 1500watt heater, hair dryer)?  Bathrooms typically have dedicated circuits as it is expected a hair dryer will get plugged in.

Comment: What did you have plugged in in those rooms and running when the breaker tripped?

Comment: Fresh Codemonger: such a configuration is likely not going to happen as NEC has a maximum spacing between outlets, and for a room to be considered a room instead of a closet it's going to be big enough to effectively require multiple outlets.

Comment: Did lights lose power? Outlets lose power? Did you lose electric baseboard heat? Some combination of those? Something else entirely? What, _exactly_ does "controls half the house" really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NEC doesn't have and actual limit for number of receptacles per circuit in *dwelling units*. It gives a complicated calculation initially based on watts per square foot, then says [NEC 210.11(B)] that the loads are to be "evenly proportioned among multioutlet branch circuits".

There is a specific rule for *other than dwelling units* of 180 watts per yoke which works out to 10 to 13 receptacles per circuit. Some people misapply that to dwelling units. In some installations that calculation works acceptably, but not always. Rules for receptacle placement in wall sections 24" or wider and distances between receptacles not crossing doorways can sometimes add up to more receptacles per square foot than is proportional.

That being said it sounds like maybe the house was out of compliance to begin with, and without knowing what the instructions to your electrician were it does sound like you may have is a breach of contract or at very least a misunderstanding by the electrician of your intensions. It is also possible he didn't understand the the full impact of the work he performed, and a larger scope and bill would be necessary to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In that one circuit powers so many outlets is bad, no doubt.

Depending upon which year NEC code was used, there really isn't a limit on the number of outlets on a single circuit.  There are specific requirements for bathrooms and kitchens, but not the rest of the home.  Rule of thumb is not more than 10 outlets for a 15 amp (14 ga wire) or 12 for a 20 amp (12 ga wire).

I think there should be a limit on the number of outlets on a circuit, but unfortunately , I don't believe code specifies that.

Best thing to do is figure out the loads that tripped the breaker and, if possible, move the load (computer? microwave? Laser printer? Plasma TV? ...) to another circuit already installed.   If that isn't practical, it might be time to install an additional circuit or two where needed. Leave the existing circuits as they are...just add 1 or 2 more where needed.

I realize this is probably not a DIY answer, but it's all I can offer.